# Preview images before uploading using JavaScript not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Here is my code that I have used for image previewing before uploading. This code works perfectly in other browsers like Chrome, IE, Safari but not in Edge, specifically for .PNG images. Please help me out. The problem is first time it is not showing any preview but if I upload JPG and then PNG image only then the PNG image preview is shown.

```
function readURL(input,id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#'+id).attr('src', e.target.result)     
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following might help

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files;
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (!file.type.match('image'))
          continue;
        var picReader = new FileReader();
        picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
          var picFile = event.target;
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
          output.insertBefore(div, null);
        });        
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="termek_file" class="file_input" multiple/>
<div id="result" class="uploadPreview">
```